# Array difference as serie of splices

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given

```
old: [a,b,    e]
new: [a,  c,d,e]
```

You could get `new` by splicing `old`:

```
 old.splice(1,1,c,d)
```

Unfortunately, it is not always possible in a single command:

```
old: [a,b    ,e,  g,h]
new: [a   c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

Splices:

```
old.splice(1,1,c,d) // [a,c,d,e,g,h]
old.splice(4,0,f)   // [a,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

Is there an algorithm that can calculate the difference of two arrays as a series of splices?

Use case: Update a list of items (e.g. in the GUI) without refreshing the entire list, but only by manipulating the existing list. (perhaps with appropriate animations for removal and insertion)

Comment: Are both the old and new array in sorted order?

Comment: Actually, it is always possible in single command: `old.splice(0, 5, a, c, d, e, f, g, h)`. You need some optimality criterion.

Comment: You might be looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem or something similar.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Yes, they would always be ordered by the same arbitrary order function.

Comment: @zch: Thanks for that link. I was searching for such algorithms.

Comment: If you have two items, is there an easy way to determine the order in which they belong?